# Is possible to acces the waveform of a song from a spotify app?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, spotify, audio-processing

I am thinking on how to build an spotify app that does beat detection (extract bpm of a song).
For that I need to access the raw audio, the waveform, and analyze it.

I am new to building spotify apps.
I know that with "libspotify" you can access raw audio. Can you do the same through the spotify apps API? And how?

For the record, currently exist two spotify apps apis:

- [Current](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/)
- [Preview](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word: no. That isn't currently available in the Apps API.

Comment: May finally be outdated @ikenndac?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're really keen on writing that beat detection code yourself, you should look at the APIs provided by the [EchoNest](http://developer.echonest.com/), which include that (and many other awesome things).

see [Getting the tempo, key signature, and other audio attributes of a song](http://developer.echonest.com/raw_tutorials/faqs/faq_04.html)

Comment: I actually wanted to write it myself. Anyway, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

There’s a new endpoint I guess. See an example https://medium.com/swlh/creating-waveforms-out-of-spotify-tracks-b22030dd442b

That uses the endpoint: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-audio-analysis

**Edit: I agree with commenter @wizbcn that this does not answer this question.** Is it sort of incorrect to leave it here because I found this SO post while searching for info about visualizing the tack's waveform as in the linked article? Maybe I should make this a comment instead?

Comment: The question talked about accessing the raw data, this doesn't do it.